# spider_closed function is not fired

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to log some data when the spider finishes working.

I make this function inside my spider.

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
        log.msg('The spider {0} finished working on'.format(self.name), level=log.INFO)
```

But this function is not getting fired.

#### I am using scrapy 0.20 with python 2.7

Please note that I can log to my log anything and actually I am logging a lot of data that I can see in my log file. so the logging is working with me.

#### Edit

I guess that I have to dispatch a signal `signals.spider_closed` but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should attach your method as a `receiver` to the [`SignalManager`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.signalmanager.SignalManager) signal dispatcher:

```
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals

class MySpider(Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        log.msg('The spider {0} finished working on'.format(self.name), level=log.INFO)
```

Also see relevant threads:

- [scrapy: Call a function when a spider quits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394184/scrapy-call-a-function-when-a-spider-quits)
- [Recording the total time taken for running a spider in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245394/recording-the-total-time-taken-for-running-a-spider-in-scrapy)

Comment: I found the solution, it is almost the same like your answer, I did this: `dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)` in my `__init__` and then, it works. is that correct please?

Comment: @SimeoniPeraparota yup, it is nicer - edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: +1 to your appreciated efforts with me. will accept your answer when the system allows